# Count until condition is reached in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum, rowwise

I need some input from you. The idea is that I would like to see how long (in rows) it takes before you can see

1. a new value in column `SUB_B1`, and
2. a new value in `SUB_B2`

i.e, how many steps is there between

1. `SUB_A1` and `SUB B1`, and
2. between `SUB A2` and `SUB B2`

I have structured the data something like this: (*I sort the index in descending order by the results column. After that I separate index B and A and place them in new columns*)

```
df.sort_values(['A','result'], ascending=[True,False]).set_index(['A','B'])
```

|  |  | result | SUB_A1 | SUB_A2 | SUB_B1 | SUB_B2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | **B** |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10_125 | 10_173 | 0.903257 | 10 | 125 | 10 | 173 |
|  | 10_332 | 0.847333 | 10 | 125 | 10 | 332 |
|  | 10_243 | 0.842802 | 10 | 125 | 10 | 243 |
|  | 10_522 | 0.836335 | 10 | 125 | 10 | 522 |
|  | 58_941 | 0.810760 | 10 | 125 | 58 | 941 |
|  | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10_173 | 10_125 | 0.903257 | 10 | 173 | 10 | 125 |
|  | 58_941 | 0.847333 | 10 | 173 | 58 | 941 |
|  | 1_941 | 0.842802 | 10 | 173 | 1 | 941 |
|  | 96_512 | 0.836335 | 10 | 173 | 96 | 512 |
|  | 10_513 | 0.810760 | 10 | 173 | 10 | 513 |

This is what I have done so far: (*edit: I think I need to  iterate over `values[]` However, I havent manage to loop beyond the first rows yet...*)

```
def func(group):
        if group.SUB_A1.values[0] == group.SUB_B1.values[0]:
            group.R1.values[0] = 1
        else:
            group.R1.values[0] = 0
        if group.SUB_A1.values[0] == group.SUB_B1.values[1] and group.R1.values[0] == 1:
            group.R1.values[1] = 2
        else:
            group.R1.values[1] = 0 

df['R1'] = 0
df.groupby('A').apply(func)
```

Expected outcome:

|  |  | result | SUB_B1 | SUB_B2 | R1 | R2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | **B** |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10_125 | 10_173 | 0.903257 | 10 | 173 | 1 | 0 |
|  | 10_332 | 0.847333 | 10 | 332 | 2 | 0 |
|  | 10_243 | 0.842802 | 10 | 243 | 3 | 0 |
|  | 10_522 | 0.836335 | 10 | 522 | 4 | 0 |
|  | 58_941 | 0.810760 | 58 | 941 | 0 | 0 |
|  | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"SUB_A": [1, -1, -2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 6, 6, 6],
     "SUB_B": [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6]},
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(1, 3), range(1, 6)], names=("A", "B"))
)
```

```
     SUB_A  SUB_B
A B              
1 1      1      1
  2     -1      2
  3     -2      3
  4      3      3
  5      3      3
2 1      4      3
  2      3      4
  3      6      6
  4      6      6
  5      6      6
```

Now this

```
equal = df.SUB_A == df.SUB_B
df["R"] = equal.groupby(equal.groupby("A").diff().fillna(True).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

leads to

```
     SUB_A  SUB_B  R
A B                 
1 1      1      1  1
  2     -1      2  0
  3     -2      3  0
  4      3      3  1
  5      3      3  2
2 1      4      3  0
  2      3      4  0
  3      6      6  1
  4      6      6  2
  5      6      6  3
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Although I'd need it in a multiindex dataset, which I should have made more explicit from the beginning. Yet, I find a solution for this.

Comment: @perrus I have included a multiindex into the example.

Comment: Hey, very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

You can iterate through the dataframe and compare current row with the previous one, then add some condition:

```
df['SUB_A2_last'] = df['SUB_A2'].shift()
count = 0
#Fill column with zeros
df['count_series'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    subA = row['sub_A2']
    subA_last = row['sub_A2_last']
    if subA == subA_last:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 0
    df.loc[index, 'count_series'] = count
```

Then repeat for B column. It is possible to get a better aproach using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and a custom function.

Comment: @Timus sorry, it was a typo. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Cheers Niki, thanks for your input. Although it did not stop counting after the condition had been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Puh! Super! Thanks for the input you guys

```
def func(group):
    for each in range(len(group)):
        if group.SUB_A1.values[0] == group.SUB_B1.values[each]:
            group.R1.values[each] = each + 1
            continue
        elif group.SUB_A1.values[0] == group.SUB_B1.values[each] and group.R1.values[each] == each + 1:
            group.R1.values[each] = each + 1
        else:
            group.R1.values[each] = 0
        return group

df['R1'] = 0
df.groupby('A').apply(func)
```